# How to use ant command line to pick my custom build.xml

Tags: android, xml, qt, ant

I have a `QtApp` for `android` which I build `command line` using the following command. It builds using ant. All great. Builds fine. Runs fine. Following the core command which creates & signs the apk for me.

```
ANT_OPTIONS=" -ant"
Path/To/androiddeployqt --sign /Path/to/MyKey.keystore MyAlias --storepass MyPassword --output android --verbose --input /path/to/android-libMyQtApp.so-deployment-settings.json $ANT_OPTIONS
```

Next, I have a few versioning customisations to do for which I need to create my own build.xml & make ant pick my custom build.xml. I read through the following ant official page which describes usage of `-buildfile` & states that you can mention the directory containing your custom build.xml.
https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

As **I want to use my custom build.xml** which I created in my project directory, **I made the following change in the command**.

```
ANT_OPTIONS=" -ant -buildfile '/Directory/containing/my_build.xml'"
Path/To/androiddeployqt --sign /Pathto/MyKey.keystore MyAlias --storepass MyPassword --output android --verbose --input /path/to/android-libMyQtApp.so-deployment-settings.json $ANT_OPTIONS
```

**But ant still picks up the default generated build.xml. What is wrong in my ANT_OPTIONS ? Does `androiddeployqt` dis-allow me from passing extra ant command line options ?**

Or, is it possible to create an ant.properties file so that ant picks up my custom build commands ? **I just want to increment the version number of my android app**

Answer (score 4):

As per [apache-ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) there are three options available to choose the build script if that is not default name (`build.xml`).

> ```
>  -buildfile <file>      use given buildfile
>     -file    <file>              ''
>     -f       <file>              ''
> ```

And you can see below that all the above versions are working:

```
- bash $~/Documents/so$ ant -buildfile build-regex.xml 
Buildfile: /home/apps/Documents/so/build-regex.xml

myTarget:
     [echo] D:/MyFolder/abc/

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
- bash $~/Documents/so$ ant -f build-regex.xml 
Buildfile: /home/apps/Documents/so/build-regex.xml

myTarget:
     [echo] D:/MyFolder/abc/

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
- bash $~/Documents/so$ ant -file build-regex.xml 
Buildfile: /home/apps/Documents/so/build-regex.xml

myTarget:
     [echo] D:/MyFolder/abc/

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

You tried the option `-buildfile` and it is strange it did not work. You may try `-f` or `-file` option.

Comment: are you trying the `ant -buildfile` command statndalone ? Or with `androiddeployqt`. In my case its a QtApp I am building command line for which I use a command line tool called `androiddeployqt`. That tool has a `-ant` option. But its not accepting `-buildfile` as a extra param to ant

Comment: As you see, it is command line `ant`, no `android`. Have tried other options though?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions until yet. command line ant works fine standalone. No doubt about it. My problem here ant's combination with `androiddeployqt` which is giving problems.

Comment: But anyways thanks for the vivid explanation. I am trying the same with my QtApp & androiddeploqt. Seems like it androiddeployqt tool is the problem. It does not recognize the ant options. trying on..

Comment: I am no voice in android. See if this link helps which has options for `androiddeployqt` - http://osxr.org:8080/qt/source/qttools/src/androiddeployqt/main.cpp

Comment: By the way, there was a space before `-ant` in ANT_OPTIONS, was it desired?

Comment: yes. you are correct. `ANT_OPTIONS` is not desired. I was anticipating `-ant` to have more options to specify custom build.xml. It would have come handy. Also, I thought if there is an option to append to `-ant`, then it will be easier for a person to reply my question by just appending the correct command to `ANT_OPTIONS`. Thanks for pointing to the source code of `androiddeployqt`. I will try to dig through if there is a way